# symfony 2 unique constraint validation with association

Tags: symfony, doctrine, doctrine-orm

I'm having trouble validating the "uniqueness" of two fields, being one of them an entity of an association. The logic is that there can't be two taxes with the same description for a single country.

Here's my (failed) attempt:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="taxes", uniqueConstraints={@ORM\UniqueConstraint(columns={"country_id", "description"})})
 * @UniqueEntity(fields={"country", "description"})
 */

class Tax
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO") 
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column()         
     */
    protected $description;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="float")
     */
    protected $value;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Country", inversedBy="taxes")
     */
    protected $country;

    //getters and setters...
}
```

When I test my app with a duplicate tax entity, the form pass the validation (when it shouldn't) and Symfony throws an error:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '1-ITBMS' for key 'country_id'
```

**UPDATE**: I found that this is a known [bug](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/1635) in Doctrine 2.1 that is fixed in Doctrine 2.2. Unfortunately, Symfony 2.0.11 (my current version) ships with Doctrine 2.1 and I don't know how to update my deps file appropriately

**UPDATE 2**: After updating my deps and deps.lock files to get the latest Doctrine 2.2.1 files as @elnur suggested below, the problem is still there: The composite unique key is created in the database but the validation is not correctly performed. Upgrading the Doctrine files alone is not solving the problem.

**UPDATE 3**: I even updated Symfony core to version 2.0.12 but it doesn't solve the problem either.

**UPDATE 4 (SOLVED)**: I found the error inside my controller. Here is my original controller code:

```
public function createAction($country_id)
{
    //...        

    if($request->getMethod() == 'POST')
    {
        $form->bindRequest($request);
        $tax->setCountry($country); //HERE IS THE ERROR...

        if($form->isValid())
        {   
            //...
        }
    }        
    //...
}
```

Setting the country **before** binding the request was the solution.

```
public function createAction($country_id)
{
    //...        

    if($request->getMethod() == 'POST')
    {            
        $tax->setCountry($country); //NOW IT WORKS...
        $form->bindRequest($request);            

        if($form->isValid())
        {   
            //...
        }
    }        
    //...
}
```

Comment: `{@ORM\UniqueConstraint(columns={"pais_id", "descripcion"})})` didn't you make a typo here: descripcion?

Comment: Your right but that was jut a typo here in StackOverflow (not in the actual code that I'm testing) because I translated my code from spanish just to make it clearer. I'm going to edit the question. Thanks

Comment: Can you explain update 4 more?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To upgrade to Doctrine 2.2.1, replace related entries in your `deps` file with these:

```
[doctrine-common]
    git=http://github.com/doctrine/common.git
    version=2.2.1

[doctrine-dbal]
    git=http://github.com/doctrine/dbal.git
    version=2.2.1

[doctrine]
    git=http://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2.git
    version=2.2.1
```

And in your `deps.lock` with these:

```
doctrine-common 2.2.1
doctrine-dbal 2.2.1
doctrine 2.2.1
```

Then run:

```
bin/vendors install
```

**UPDATE**

Since upgrading Doctrine didn't work, try the [`UniqueEntityCaseInsensitive`](https://github.com/elnur/ElnurValidatorBundle/blob/master/Validator/Constraints/UniqueEntityCaseInsensitive.php) constraint from my [`ValidatorBundle`](https://github.com/elnur/ElnurValidatorBundle).

Install the bundle, import the constraint:

```
use Elnur\ValidatorBundle\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntityCaseInsensitive;
```

and replace your

```
@UniqueEntity(fields={"country", "description"})
```

with

```
@UniqueEntityCaseInsensitive(fields={"country", "description"})
```

Comment: I've heard that Doctrine has now it's own bundle. Upgrading my deps files as you show doesn't require to change some namespaces?

Comment: All I had to do in one project is to change just a couple of lines — and that was it. Also what I gave you has nothing to with any bundles — it upgrades Doctrine itself.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @elnur but after updating my deps and deps.lock files the issue is still there, the validation is not performed at all using the code I wrote above. The composite unique key is created in the database but the validation is not working as expected. Seems like updating the doctrine files alone was not enough.

Comment: Hmm. You should probably add code of your form type and controller.

Comment: Thanks for the help man, checking my controller makes me realize my mistake. I updated the question with the solution.